# Explicit bound on $\int_0^\infty t^{-(u+1/u)} du$?

Tags: integration, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds, laplace-method

I would like to give an explicit bound on $\int_0^\infty t^{u+1/u} u^k du$. It's easy to reduce to $k=0,1$ by integration by parts, and I take one can reduce matters to the case $k=0$ alone by substituting $u$ by $1/u$.

Laplace's method gives us the leading-order term, but how do I get a bound with explicit constants in the error term? Think of t as large.

Correction: I meant $t^{-(u+1/u)}$. I won't change this so as not to invalidate the answer below. So, think of $t$ as positive and close to $0$, rather of thinking of $t$ as small.

Comment: Large?  If $t \ge 1$  the integrand $>1$ and the integral diverges.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed a minus in the exponent. So, please think of $t$ as small :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $t\ge 1$, the integral diverges. If $0<t<1$, we can write
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ + \infty } {t^{u + \frac{1}{u}} u^k {\rm d}u} & = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{\left( {u + \frac{1}{u}} \right)\log t} u^k {\rm d}u} \\ & = \left( {\frac{{2\left| {\log t} \right|}}{2}} \right)^{ - (k + 1)} \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - s - \frac{{(2\left| {\log t} \right|)^2 }}{{4s}}} \frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{s^{ - (k + 1) + 1} }}} 
\\ & = 2K_{ - (k + 1)} (2\left| {\log t} \right|) = 2K_{k + 1} (2\left| {\log t} \right|),
\end{align*}
where $K_\nu$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind (cf. [$(10.32.10)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E10)). Then, by [$\S10.40(\text{iii})$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40.iii) in the DLMF,
$$
2K_{k + 1} (2\left| {\log t} \right|) \le \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{\left| {\log t} \right|}}} t^2 \left( {1 + \frac{{4(k + 1)^2  - 1}}{{8\left| {\log t} \right|}}\exp \left( {\frac{{4(k + 1)^2  - 1}}{{8\left| {\log t} \right|}}} \right)} \right)
$$
for any $0<t<1$, and this is asymptotically sharp as $t\to 0^+$.